# Choose to store table exclusively on disk in Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite

I understand the native persistence mode of Apache Ignite allows to store as much as possible data in memory - and the potential remaining data on disk.

Is it possible to manually choose which table I want to store in memory and which I want to store EXCLUSIVELY on disk? If I want to save costs, should I just give Ignite a lot of disk space and just a small amount of memory? What if I know some tables should return results as fast as possible while other tables have lower priorities in terms of speed (even if they are accessed more often)? Is there any feature to prioritize data storage into memory at table level or any other level?

Answer (score 3):

You can define two different data regions - one with small amount of memory and enabled persistence and second without persistence, but with bigger max memory size: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/memory-configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a cache (which contains rows for a table) to be stored exclusively on disk.

When you add a row to table it gets stored in [Durable Memory](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/durable-memory), which is always located in RAM. Later it may be flushed to disk via [Checkpointing](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/persistence-checkpointing) process, which will use checkpoint page buffer, which is also in RAM. So you can have a separate region with low memory usage (see another answer) but you can't have data **exclusively** on disk.

When you access data it will always be pulled from disk to Durable Memory, too.